# Getting div container height to dynamically resize to accommodate footer

Tags: jquery, css

I'm creating a website with different display modes (**admin**, **display**, **user**).

I want the container's height to dynamically resize depending on what display mode so it takes up the space between the header/footer.

In some cases there is no footer (**display**), so the container should take up the rest of the space.

On top of this, I want the container to overflow automatically within the boundaries it has been set.

How can I go about achieving this?

Here is my code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/UgQLS/2/

Currently the container height is set to 100%, and when text overflows it is covered up by the footer.

The different display modes:

```
$(".admin_btn").click(function() {
    $('.user').hide();
    $('.admin').show();
});

$(".user_btn").click(function() {
    $('.admin').hide();
    $('.user').show();
});

$(".display_btn").click(function() {
    $('.admin').hide();
    $('.user').hide();
    $('.display').show();
}); 

$('.admin').on('click', '#sendlogout', function (e) {
    $('#login_confirm').hide()
    $('#hide_admin').show()
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend creating a fixed footer region and placing your various footer elements into it. You can then either use css classes to vary the bottom padding on your content to accomodate the dynamic footer content, or recalculate the content container padding based on the current footer height.

note: padding the container allows you to scroll the content hidden by the fixed footer into view

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xDGT6/) you can see a recalculation approach

```
$(".admin_btn").click(function() {
    $('.user').hide();
    $('.admin').show();
    reflow();
});

function reflow() {
    $('.container').css('padding-bottom', $('#footer').height() );
}
```

but you could as easily add a class to your content when you click on a button, and set the `padding-bottom` that way

```
$(".admin_btn").click(function() {
    $('.user').hide();
    $('.admin').show();
    $('.container').toggleClass('admin');
});
```

css

```
.container.admin {
     padding-bottom: 156px;
}
```

if you use a css approach, you can eliminate the `hide()` and `show()` calls by setting the display on the footer elements based on the container class, like so:

```
$(".admin_btn").click(function() {
    $('.container').toggleClass('showadmin');
});
```

css

```
.user, .admin {
    display: none;
}

.showadmin .admin {
    display: inherit;
}

.container.showadmin {
    padding-bottom: 156px;
}
```